# Does the word "amount" have any particular meaning here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"In previous eras, such as the Iron Age and the Bronze Age, the
discovery of new elements brought forth seemingly unending
numbers of new inventions. Now the combinations may truly be
unending. We are now witnessing a fundamental shift in our
resource demands. At no point in human history have we used
more elements, in more combinations, and in increasingly refined
**amounts**."

Q. What's the exact meaning of the word "amount" here?
Is it the same meaning as in "a small **amount** of sugar"? Or some other meaning?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing special about the meaning here. "Quantity" would be an exact synonym (in the sentence, "quantities").

Comment: It's a slightly odd usage. My guess is it's referring to the fact that increasingly today in a range of industrial / material science contexts we specifically require ***refined, pure*** elements and compounds. Sometimes because it's essential in some ***mixture*** (I imagine they specify extremely pure gallium arsenide in chip manufacture), and sometimes because something like very pure copper or gold is much better at conducting electricity than the kind of "not-exactly-pure" stuff people *used* to trade on international metal markets.

Comment: (As I understand it, modern materials science often involves very carefully measured & mixed small quantities of "exotic" elements, used to "**dope**" some material to achieve significant improvements to some relevant characteristic of the material being produced.)